# navigating from popup to popup in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am working with `Objective C` using `xcode` and `SUP 2.1.3` as backend.I am verymuch new to the technology.I have created a project with master detail as the design template.In that in the detail view I am using a popup to display some details.And also I have a button over there. When I click in this button I have to go to the next `UIView` in popup itself.

For that I have created two more `UIViewControllers` (viewController1 and viewController2).
And in detailview I have written the code for a popup like,

```
  -(void)popupAgain
    {
        ViewController1 *viewController = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];

        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController release];
    }
```

And I put a button over their in that popup, I am calling the next popupAgain funcion to get viewController2 like

```
 -(IBAction)next:(id)sender
    {
        [self popupAgain];
    }

 -(void)popupAgain
    {
        ViewController2 *viewController_new = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

        viewController_new.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController_new release];
    }
```

Now the problem is when I click on the next button I have to dismiss the first popup and display the second.But I am not able to dissmiss the first one even if I am writing the code [self dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in the action for next button like,

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    [self dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    [self popupAgain];
}
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.Or do you have any other idea regarding this?I am very much new to the technology.Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1

Dismissing a Presented View Controller

When it comes time to dismiss a presented view controller, the preferred approach is to let the presenting view controller dismiss it. In other words, whenever possible, the same view controller that presented the view controller should also take responsibility for dismissing it. Although there are several techniques for notifying the presenting view controller that its presented view controller should be dismissed, the preferred technique is delegation. For more information, see “Using Delegation to Communicate with Other Controllers.”